# Как выделить память для массива функций

Tags: c++, ооп, функции, динамические-массивы

```
class name {
    public:
    name(int);
    double(*act)(double);

    double f1(double);
    double f2(double);
    double f3(double);
};

name::name(int i) {
    this->act = new (double[i](double));
}
```

> ```
> error: creating array of functions
> ```

Вот так ругается компилятор. Как можно реализовать такой динамический массив?

Comment: Каким образом вы хотите выделить память под функцию/метод?
В этом нет никакого смысла, функции - это, по сути, указатели на участоки кода. Вот приравнять один указатель на функцию к другому можно, ровно как и выделить массив указателей на функции, но никак не выделить память под функцию.

Comment: В языках С и  С++ нет и не может быть "массивов функций". Невозможно объявить такой тип.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать, что должно получиться в итоге и как вы планируете этим пользоваться. Потому что сейчас вы пытаетесь сделать очень странную и скорее всего бессмысленную вещь. Вы, конечно, можете сделать массив указателей на функцию, но, возможно, ваше желание можно удовлетворить иным, более простым и удобным способом.

Comment: Я почти уверен, что вам нужен массив указателей на функции.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если говорить про обычные функции:

```
int foo1(float)
{
    return 1;
}

int foo2(float)
{
    return 2;
}

int foo3(float)
{
    return 3;
}

int main()
{
    // в типе должна быть описана сигнатура необходимой функции
    using fun_type = int(*)(float); // int - возвращаемый тип
    // float - аргумент, (*) - означает что мы хотим создать указатель на функцию

    // создали массив указателей на функции
    // поместили адреса фукций foo1, foo2, foo3
    fun_type funs[] = { &foo1, &foo2, &foo3 };

    // вызываем функцию (в данном случае foo1)
    int result = funs[0](10.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

Однако в вашем случае необходимы не просто указатели на функцию, а указатели на методы класса. Это другие сущности и, настолько они особенны, что даже не поддаются void*. Но такая проблема также решается:

```
class widget
{
public:
    // имеется несколько методов с одинаковой сигнатурой
    void foo1(int);

    void foo2(int);

    void foo3(int);

    // внимание на модификатор const
    // объяснения ниже
    void foo4_c(int) const;
};

int main()
{

    // объявление массива указателей на метод класса widget
    // как и в случае с обычным указателем, этот указатель
    // просто локальная переменная
    // эти указатели не относятся к какому-нибудь конкретному объекту
    // они относятся к классу widget в целом
    void(widget::*fun_ptr[3])(int);


    // устанавливаем несколько конкретных значений
    // можно было при объявлении инициализировать списком {}
    fun_ptr[0] = &widget::foo1;
    fun_ptr[1] = &widget::foo2;
    fun_ptr[2] = &widget::foo3;

    // по поводу const в объявлении метода:
    // const является часть сигнатуры метода!
    // поэтому следующий код не скомпилируется
    // по причине разных типов указателей
    // fun_ptr[2] = &widget::foo4_c; // error!

    // для const-методов необходимо указать спецификатор const
    void(widget::*const_fun_ptr)(int) const;

    const_fun_ptr = &widget::foo4_c; // ok!

    // создается конкретный объект класса
    widget obj;

    // и указатель на динамически распределенный объект
    widget *ptr_to_obj = new widget();

    // собственно использование указателей
    // obj.* - обращение к члену указателю
    // т.к. fun_ptr массив мы указываем еще индекс
    // по которому находится нужный метод
    // необходимо взять в скобки
    (obj.*fun_ptr[0])(10);

    // для указателей на объекты используется
    // чуть-чуть другой синтаксис
    (ptr_to_obj->*fun_ptr[0])(10);

    delete ptr_to_obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Создать динамический массив указателей на обычную функцию не слишком сложно.

```
using fptr = void(*)(int);
fptr* fptrs = new fptr[10];
delete[] fptrs;
```

Чуть сложнее дело обстоит с указателями на методы. У меня получилось достичь необходимого результата следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

class widget
{
public:
    void foo1(int)
    {
        std::cout << "foo1\n";
    }

    void foo2(int)
    {
        std::cout << "foo2\n";
    }

    void foo3(int)
    {
        std::cout << "foo3\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    void(widget::*fptr)(int);

    using fptr_type = decltype(fptr);

    fptr_type* fptrs = new fptr_type[3];

    fptrs[0] = &widget::foo1;
    fptrs[1] = &widget::foo2;
    fptrs[2] = &widget::foo3;

    widget a;

    (a.*fptrs[0])(10);
    (a.*fptrs[1])(10);
    (a.*fptrs[2])(10);

    delete[] fptrs;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `decltype` не нужен, можно просто `using fptr_type = void (widget::*)(int);`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы хотите что-то вроде этого?

```
class Name {
public:
    Name(int);
    using func = double(*)(double);
    func* act;

};

Name::Name(int i)
{
    act = new func[i];
}
```

На всякий случай, исходя из набора у вас функций-членов `f#` - для функций-членов массив надо объявлять иначе.