# Получить адрес функции

Tags: c++, указатели, методы

Пробовал получать адрес функции по-разному:

```
void* address = &pContext->VSGetConstantBuffers;
reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR/*LPVOID*/>(pContext->VSGetConstantBuffers)
```

Бесполезно. Компилятор пишет либо недопустимая операция с выражением привязанной функции-члена, либо невозможно преобразовать. Как можно получить адрес этой функции? Он мне нужен для сравнения

Comment: Для получения адреса нестатического метода класса следует использовать синтаксис `&ClassName::FunctionName`. Полученный адрес нельзя будет преобразовать в `void *` или `DWORD_PTR`. Однако непонятно, зачем (и с чем) может понадобиться сравнивать указатель на `VSGetConstantBuffers`...

Comment: @VTT, :: не работает. pContext это ID3D11DeviceContext*

Comment: Работает, `pContext` в этой записи вообще не нужен.

Comment: @VTT, Понял пытаюсь делать так: ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetConstantBuffers. если его нельзя преобразовать в void или dword_ptr, тогда как мне получить адрес функции (число)?

Comment: `auto p{&ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetConstantBuffers};`, адрес (число) получить не получится, так как адрес нестатического метода - это составная структура. И да, по-прежнему непонятно, с чем вы собираетесь его сравнивать. Адрес-то будет один и тот же

Comment: @VTT, не понимаю почему нельзя так получить адрес. Может тогда получить адрес составной структуры и найти смещение? 
Я перехватываю функции для оптимизации кода и пытаюсь понять, ту функцию, которую я перехватил является той, которую мне нужна, или нет

Comment: "Я перехватываю функции для оптимизации кода" - с подробного изложения этой части и стоило начать вопрос. А так это просто проблема XY...

Comment: @VTT, а я то думал, почему для d3d11 функций обычно используют VMT для получения адреса. Я так понял, через указатель можно получать адрес только на экспортные/глобальные функции?

Comment: Ну формально "простой" указатель можно получить на свободные функции и статические методы классов. Такие понятия, как "экспортные" и "глобальные" в С++ отсутствуют.

Comment: @user2173645: Адрес нестатического метода класса не является "адресом функции". Это сущности разной природы. А если метод с класса еще и является *виртуальным*, то фактического адреса конкретного метода получить невозможно вообще. Адрес виртуального метода - это обычно адрес промежуточной "вызывалки", которая одинакова для всех методов с одинаковым смещением в VMT. Т.е. сравнивать такие адреса бесполезно - они будут одинаковыми даже если конечные виртуальные функции разные.

Comment: по поводу указателей на методы класса можете посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853818/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9/853877#853877)

Answer (score -1):

```
void function(){
    cout << "hello";
}
int main(){
    cout << &function;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Пробовали запускать? Печатает `1` вместо адреса.